# Getting a string of specifc length from Maximo Manage API (oslc.where query)

Tags: javascript, api, where-clause, maximo, oslc

I'm working with the IBM Maximo Manage API(v8), and currently Im trying to get the largest item number (itemnum) that starts with 99 and is exactly 7 digits long from our item database. The part I'm struggling with is trying to get an item number that is only 7 digits long.

Currently, I have:
`oslc.where=status="active" and itemnum="99%"&oslc.select=itemnum&oslc.pageSize=1&oslc.orderBy=-itemnum`
This gets an item that is active, has an item# starting with 99, and selects the first item after sorting by greatest to lowest. I've tried adding `and len(itemnum)=7`, and replacing `itemnum="99%"` with `itemnum="99_____"` but to no avail. I've tried going through [the docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/maximo-manage/8.3.0) but couldn't find any info about this.